# How can I run a function with a String as formal for the function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a function that changes a value for each line of code, the Value is a String and when I run the function, y doesn't do anything, not even an error message. If I assign the function to a dataframe, it shows as 0 elements, but if I run the code within the function as a single element it will run and do the code inside the function

```
id="187B339C-26F8-40A1-948F-0F9803761850"

outsporzonaprueba<-function(guid55){

  o1<-filter(mydata, desc=="Bunt Out" | desc=="Fly out" | desc=="Ground out" | desc=="Strikeout Looking" | desc=="Strikeout Swinging", zone=="zona1", guid5==guid55)

  o2<-filter(mydata, desc=="Bunt Out" | desc=="Fly out" | desc=="Ground out" | desc=="Strikeout Looking" | desc=="Strikeout Swinging", zone=="zona2", guid5==guid55)

  o3<-filter(mydata, desc=="Bunt Out" | desc=="Fly out" | desc=="Ground out" | desc=="Strikeout Looking" | desc=="Strikeout Swinging", zone=="zona3", guid5==guid55)

}

opz<-outsporzonaprueba(id)
```

Comment: Can you post a small repex with a dataframe that is similar to the one that you are trying to use? Also within a function the R code will only return the last object created. So your function will only return the o3 object. If you want it to return all of the objects you need to add then to a list and return them,

Comment: As written, your function will return the value in `o3`. However, because the final line of the function writes this value into the variable, it returns "silently". Adding `return(o3)` as the final line of your function will explicitly return it (and print it out, etc). You could do `return(list(o1, o2, o3))` to return an object with all three.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not returning any value in the end of function you are not getting any output.

Including `return(list(o1,o2,o3))` *should give output*.

```
    id="187B339C-26F8-40A1-948F-0F9803761850"

    outsporzonaprueba<-function(data, guid55){

      o1<-filter(data, desc=="Bunt Out" | desc=="Fly out" | desc=="Ground out" | desc=="Strikeout Looking" | desc=="Strikeout Swinging", zone=="zona1", guid5==guid55)

      o2<-filter(data, desc=="Bunt Out" | desc=="Fly out" | desc=="Ground out" | desc=="Strikeout Looking" | desc=="Strikeout Swinging", zone=="zona2", guid5==guid55)

      o3<-filter(data, desc=="Bunt Out" | desc=="Fly out" | desc=="Ground out" | desc=="Strikeout Looking" | desc=="Strikeout Swinging", zone=="zona3", guid5==guid55)

      return(list(o1,o2,o3)) }

    opz<-outsporzonaprueba(data= mydata,guid55 = id)
    opz
```

Comment: The problem is that the datasets o1 o2 or o3 arent even created when i run the function, if i run the o2 line or o3 by itself it does create the datasets

Comment: You should pass mydata in function argument. Since mydata is not passed in the function it's behaving weirdly. See the edited function

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly kind of confused by what you're asking.
From what I understand, your problem is that, when you run `outsporzonaprueba(id)`, the dataframes inside the function (i.e. `o1`, `o2`, and `o3`) are not being created.
 Is this correct?

If so, that's because they're defined inside the environment of the function. You want them to be assigned in the global environment, so use `<<-` instead of `<-`.

e.g.

```
id="187B339C-26F8-40A1-948F-0F9803761850"

outsporzonaprueba <- function(guid55) {
    o1 <<- filter(mydata, ..., guid5==guid55)

    o2 <<- filter(mydata, ..., guid5==guid55)

    o3 <<- filter(mydata, ..., guid5==guid55)
  }

opz <- outsporzonaprueba(id)
```

**Safer Solution**
There is a slight issue with `<<-`, namely that it will recursively check the parent environments for the assigned variable (and then create the variable in the global scope if it isn't found).

If you want to be sure about the scope in which your variable is defined, use `assign()`:

```
outsporzonaprueba <- function(guid55) {
    assign('o1', filter(mydata, ..., guid5==guid55), envir = .GlobalEnv)

    assign('o2', filter(mydata, ..., guid5==guid55), envir = .GlobalEnv)

    assign('o3', filter(mydata, ..., guid5==guid55), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
```